# Replacement of @TransactionConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-test

Currently, I am using below configuration my test classes-

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false) 
@Transactional
```

As `@TransactionConfiguration` is deprecated, What can be the replacement for that-

I have tried -

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
@Commit
```

But I am getting the below error-

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Test class [ca.aeso.dt.dao.impl.AssetAttributeDaoImplTest] **is annotated with both @Rollback and @TransactionConfiguration, but only one is permitted.**
>       at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.isDefaultRollback(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:383)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.isRollback(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:412)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:201)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:269)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, `@Commit` is equivalent to setting the default rollback mode to `false`.

In addition, the default name for the transaction manager is "transactionManager". So you can just delete the declaration of the qualifier and use `@Transactional` on its own.

If the exception is complaining about the use of `@TransactionConfiguration`, then you must have it declared somewhere, either on the test class or on a superclass. The solution is to simply delete the complete `@TransactionConfiguration` declaration.

Regards,

Sam *(author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)